# What is the content of character attributes like NSFontAttributeName?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I was reading the apple documentation to learn how to format text for iOS. I came across an attributed string and most of it made sense to me. However, while looking up the different kinds of attributes, I saw that they are all declared as NSString. 
For example:

```
NSString *const NSFontAttributeName;
NSString *const NSParagraphStyleAttributeName;
...
...
```

We pass in these string objects in a dictionary with the value being that particular attribute (e.g., a UIFont object). However, what I do not understand is what the content of that string has to do with the attribute itself. Do they just contain the name of the attribute? (i.e NSFontAttributeName might contain a string like @"NSFontAttribute")

Surely there must be a reason why has apple to chosen to do it this way?

Edit: My question isn't about why they use a string object as a key to the dictionary but why they use a predefined constant string object named NSFontAttributeName instead of allowing us to manually pass in a string @"NSFontAttribute" as the key. That's why I wondered whether the contents of their predefined string object has anything to do with this.

Comment: They are just some plain string, it can be foo or bar or anything. Why dont you use NSLog to see what actually they contain ?

Comment: My question, was more about how the content of that string actually relates to the attribute itself, and what good reasons there may be for Apple choosing to have done it this way. 

I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Those are just key values for using in the map, aren't they?

Comment: The content of the NSString is not really relevant. What's important, is that they are used as a key of a `NSDictionary`. Use `NSString` as key is quite useful when you want to debug and see directly the key/values without doing something special with overwriting `description` of a custom NSObject.

Comment: Yes, but why not just pass in a string such as @"NSFontAttribute" as the key to the UIFont object? What's the reason for choosing a predefined constant string object named NSFontAttributeName?

Comment: Autocomplete, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, Apple uses an NSDictionary to contain an arbitrary set of key/value pairs. Doing it this way means you have a lot of flexibility because you can have no attributes, one attribute, or two dozen attributes with the same programming interface. And if in two years time there are attributes available that you haven't even thought about, Apple doesn't have to introduce any new APIs to support you setting these attributes.

The reason for using a constant instead of a string literal is that the compiler can save you if you misspell a name. If you wrote @"NSFontattribute" instead of @"NSFontAttribute", the compiler wouldn't know that you got it wrong.

Comment: I get it now, but I always thought that the convention of defining anything meant to be constant is to use a macro. Something like: 

#define NS_FONT_ATTRIBUTE @"..."

This also prevents compiler errors, as well as helps with the auto-complete.

Comment: Preprocessor macros are generally considered a worse construct than an actual language symbol. The preprocessor is little more than a gross hack. You'll find languages, libraries, and frameworks moving away from macros as they modernize.

Comment: What about the use of enums? 
Or is that just an alternative and you could use either one in scenarios like this?

Comment: Enums are better than preprocessor macros for integer constants, but doesn't help for attributes. Attributes need to be objects, since they are stored in collections, like dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

As the attributes are expressed in an `NSDictionary` and you can only hold Objective-C objects in Objective-C collection classes, you have to use an object of some sort.  They could have used enumerated integer values, wrapped in `NSNumber` objects, instead:

```
typedef enum {
    KEYONE,
    KEYTWO
} KeyValues;

NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionary];
attributes[@(KEYONE)] = @"The attribute";
```

One advantage of using an `NSString` as a key is that it's easier to debug at the slight expense of generating the dictionary key hash from the string (which must be very slightly more expensive than generating it from an `NSNumber` object).